# "INSERT IF NOT EXISTS", ELSE UPDATE certain columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL Workbench (6.3) and I'm trying to create a stored procedure with a specific "INSERT IF NOT EXSISTS" but I think I don't do it well. By the way, I did read this topic http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html and tried both examples, it didn't work. Here is the statement :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `onPlayerJoin`(
    IN uuid CHAR(36),
    IN nickname CHAR(16),
    IN firstConnection TIMESTAMP,
    IN lastConnection TIMESTAMP
)

BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `test`.`player` (`playerUuid`, `playerNickname`, `playerFirstConnection`, `playerLastConnection`)
        VALUES (uuid, nickname, firstConnection, lastConnection);
        UPDATE `test`.`player` SET
        `playerNickname` = nickname,
        `playerLastConnection` = lastConnection
        WHERE `playerUuid` = uuid;
END
```

IF the PK isn't found, INSERT it. ELSE, UPDATE certain columns. (that I can specified) However, it seems that it updates every column, which I would like to restrict to certain columns. Here is my procedure : http://pastebin.com/NfcdU9Rb !

Optional question : is it injection-safe ?

Comment: An SQL-injection can only occur from the application code that accesses your SQL code.  Thus, in the context of your question on MySQL only, the question of "Is it injection-safe?" cannot be answered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Russ, and your edit !

Answer (score 1):

Use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Kindly refer the link for details:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I tried to modify the current procedure, here it is now : http://pastebin.com/AiKn7jQg However, the firstConnection column is also updated, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @MajorSquirrel : its working fine. Please check on provided link  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6181/1